# how can I have shadows around a div element?

Tags: jquery, css, html, cross-browser

I'm looking for a way to have a very nice shadow around `div` "boxes".

How can this be done in all browsers?

I've done research and found that people have many examples of shadows that only work in more powerful browsers.

Should I somehow use images? How could I do this? Any ideas?

Comment: Any special requirements what browser versions must be supported?

Comment: IE 6 and up and whatever version of Safari, Firefox, and I <3 Chrome lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few options. [CSS3 box shadows](http://www.css3.info/preview/box-shadow/) is one of them. You can also use [CSS3PIE](http://css3pie.com/) for browsers that don't support the CSS3 box shadows yet, but you'll find it won't look exactly like the CSS3 shadows in more modern browsers. Beyond that, you can use drop shadows you create in something like Photoshop and place them just "behind" your div with another div using a background image and using positioning to offset your "top" div so the shadow is revealed.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to support old browsers like IE7 etc., you should use images. Otherwise you can try anything like this:

```
div.shadow {
   -moz-box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px #777;
   -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px #777;
   box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px #777;
}
```

and of course use it via `<div class="shadow">…</div>`